# PHP/HTML incrementing variable by submit button

Tags: php, html

I'm very new to php and html and need help understanding how buttons work when altering data.

I'm displaying information on a page by using an integer to point to a position in an array.

```
$currentQuestion = $questions[$currentNumber];
```

When the button is pressed, I want to increment the integer variable

```
$currentNumber += 1;
```

and then reload the page.

How would that work?

Here is my relevant code:

```html
$currentNumber = 0;

$currentQuestion = $questions[$currentNumber];

echo $currentQuestion->getQuestion().'<br />';

foreach($currentQuestion->getAnswers() as $possibleAnswer)
{
    if ($currentQuestion->getType() == QuestionType::SINGLECHOICE){
        echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$currentQuestion->getQuestion().'" value="'.array_search($possibleAnswer->get_answer(), $currentQuestion->getAnswers()).'">'.$possibleAnswer->get_answer().'<br />';
    } else if ($currentQuestion->getType() == QuestionType::MULTICHOICE){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$currentQuestion->getQuestion().'" value="'.array_search($possibleAnswer->get_answer(), $currentQuestion->getAnswers()).'">'.$possibleAnswer->get_answer().'<br />';
    }

}

?>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Next Question' onClick="window.location.reload()" />

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see I'm just refreshing the page on click of the button, but I'm guessing I'll need to replace it with a script of function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP is a stateless language so on page refresh your information(counter in this case) is "lost", or rather reset. You'll have to use a more persistent storage in which you'll stash your counter. [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) comes to mind here. Store your counter in the session, grab it, increment it, store it again and repet.

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a go